# How to deploy React App to IIS on Windows Server?

Tags: reactjs, iis

I'm having difficulty deploying my react app on a Windows server (IIS). I have executed the npm run build command and copied the build folder to the server, however the app display a blank page when I browse to the website.

Please assist, been struggling with this for two days now.

When I look at the developer console in Chrome I get these errors below:

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/static/js/2.74a5bd4f.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/static/css/main.2cfecded.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/static/css/2.818011ed.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/static/js/main.ac3e9509.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/static/js/2.74a5bd4f.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/static/js/main.ac3e9509.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 GET http://localhost/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: I actually solved this by adding homepage: "." to the package.json file